# How to convert struct's function to C

Tags: c++, c, struct

I am using C++ library but I have to convert to C below structure because of some reason.

I find a library from github as a C++ and it has like this struct :

```
struct BRIDGE_TREE
{
    ...

void SetBridgeIdentifier (unsigned short settablePriorityComponent, unsigned short treeIndex, const unsigned char address[6])
    {
        BridgeIdentifier.SetPriorityAndMstid (settablePriorityComponent, treeIndex);
        BridgeIdentifier.SetAddress (address);
        UpdateBridgePriorityFromBridgeIdentifier();
    }

..}
```

And this struct and function calling in below function:

```
 STP_BRIDGE* STP_CreateBridge (unsigned int portCount,
                                  unsigned int mstiCount,
                                  unsigned int maxVlanNumber,
                                  const STP_CALLBACKS* callbacks,
                                  const unsigned char bridgeAddress[6],
                                  unsigned int debugLogBufferSize)
    {
STP_BRIDGE* bridge = (STP_BRIDGE*) callbacks->allocAndZeroMemory (sizeof (STP_BRIDGE)); 
    assert (bridge != NULL);
    ...
        bridge->trees [CIST_INDEX]->SetBridgeIdentifier (0x8000, CIST_INDEX, bridgeAddress);
    ..
    }
```

How can I use `SetBridgeIdentifier` function in C like this. I am looking for the solutions for a long time. I am a new for C++.

Comment: Do you mean: You want to re-write the library in C or: The library can be written in C++ but you want to be able to use it from C?

Comment: Do not think in relation to the library, I will not convert the library, I just asked how I can convert the corresponding struct function to C . Focus on main question without library.

Comment: point of my question is not whether this is about the library or just one function. The point is whether you want to merely be able to call the function from C, or want to re-write the function in C.

Comment: I want to rewrite the function in C. I can already run C ++ code with C. My goal is to learn how to write in function C

Comment: `bridge->trees [CIST_INDEX]->SetBridgeIdentifier (0x8000, CIST_INDEX, bridgeAddress)` doesn't call `void SetBridgeIdentifier (const BRIDGE_ID& newBridgeIdentifier)`. That are two different functions. What exactly do you want to convert?

Comment: @ThomasSablik sorry my mistake, I copied false funtion to inside I edited question

Answer (score 1):

A `struct` in C++ is the same as a class. The only difference between the two is if you don’t specify the visibility of the members, they will be by default public in the `struct` and `private` in the class. This also extends to inheritance; if you don’t specify anything then the `struct` will inherit publicly from its base class, but the `class` will inherit privately.

So the choice boils down essentially to convention. You use a `struct` to represent a bundle of elements that needs to be grouped logically together. You use a `class` when you're modeling a concept, and when that concept does *things* and has responsibilities.

That being said, to implement your code in pure C, you need to implement the methods as functions, and pass a pointer to the `struct` that will act as `this`.

Here's a quick example :

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
typedef struct sSOMETHING
{
  int Id;
  void SetId(int newId) { Id = newId; };
} Something;
 
int main()
{
    Something stInstance;
    stInstance.SetId(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's how it could be refactored in C :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sSOMETHING
{
  int Id;
} Something;


void SetId(Something* something, int newId)
{
  something->Id = newId;
};
 
int main(void) {
    Something stInstance;
    SetId(&stInstance, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the `SetId` method was extracted from the `Something` class and a function was created, taking a pointer from the `struct` as a parameter. This way, you can have multiple instances of `Something` and it still works.

The code excerpt you provided doesn't show enough to implement a working example, nor is it the scope of StackOverflow to implement it for you. I don't know what `STP_BRIDGE` does, `SetBridgeIdentifier()` is referencing an unknown `BridgeIdentifier`, and `BRIDGE_TREE` is incomplete.

But this should get you started :

```
typedef struct sBRIDGE_TREE
{
  [...]
}
BRIDGE_TREE;

void SetBridgeIdentifier (BRIDGE_TREE* bridgeTree, unsigned short settablePriorityComponent, unsigned short treeIndex, const unsigned char address[6])
{
  SetPriorityAndMstid(bridgeTree, settablePriorityComponent, treeIndex);
  BridgeIdentifier.SetAddress(bridgeTree, address);
  UpdateBridgePriorityFromBridgeIdentifier(bridgeTree);
}

void SetPriorityAndMstid(BRIDGE_TREE* bridgeTree, unsigned short settablePriorityComponent, unsigned short treeIndex)
{
  [...]
}

void BridgeIdentifier.SetAddress(BRIDGE_TREE* bridgeTree, const unsigned char address[6])
{
  [...]
}

void UpdateBridgePriorityFromBridgeIdentifier(BRIDGE_TREE* bridgeTree)
{
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed SetBridgeIdentifier function please check again. How can I use these implements into my code ?

Comment: @ThomasSablik You're right, of course. Thanks for the input ; english isn't my first language.

Comment: _"The only difference between the two is if you don’t specify the visibility of the members, they will be by default public in the struct and private in the class."_ That's not correct. It's not only the members. It's also the inheritance. But that's nitpicking. I gave you my up.

Comment: That's okay to nitpick. I'll edit to make sure my answer's as complete and accurate as possible.